# Z- Index isn't working to make div that contains dropdown menu overlap navigation

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, z-index, overlapping

I'm currently building a site and would really love my "4 Locations" drop down menu to work. However the navigation menu is overlapping it. My initial thought was to us Z-index to stack it on top of the main navigation but it isn't helping. What can I do?? to view it: go to http://pcfm.adamerica.me/

This is the CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.location-dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.location-dropbtn:hover, .location-dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container div - needed to position the dropdown content */
.location-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    z-index: 110001;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.location-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 110001;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.location-dropdown-content a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    z-index: 110001;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.location-dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e49
}

 /* Show the dropdown menu */
.show {
    display:block;
    z-index: 110001;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
header {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .location-dropdown .show has z-index: 110001. 
Your .responsive-header class has z-index:100000 (that's way is working properly on media less than 980px )

On media bigger than 980px:

Your header with class="header2 sticky" has z-index: 100000000. HERE is the problem, change this header z-index to 110000 and it will work properly.